# Android - programmatically creating view progressBar

Tags: java, android, layout, progress-bar

How to create horizontal progessBar without XML or how to declare XML properties without XML contentView?

I have layout in .java file and I want to set progressBar to horizontal and set its width/location.

```
RelativeLayout fv = new RelativeLayout(this);
panel = new Panel(this);
fv.addView(panel);
ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(this);
//pb.? - progress bar parameters
fv.addView(pb);
setContentView(fv);
```

Oh, and it can't be a pop-up window. I need progressBar on top of touch-enabled canvas layer..

Comment: Any luck getting this to work?

Comment: @hopia yea, but I hardly remember it.. Did something like this: RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
  setContentView(rl);
  panel = new Panel(this, content, W, H);
  panel.requestFocus();
  rl.addView(panel);
  pb = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
  pb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(sWidth, 10));
  rl.addView(pb);
  setContentView(rl);

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the constructor, do this:

```
ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
```

You can replace the null with an AttributeSet, typically you would need one of Android's AttributSets anyway.
You can then set its width/location using the standard View methods.

Comment: Can you tell me how exactly do I add these attributes? This code is good, gives me horizontal scrollbar but I keep getting crit error (I'm out of work, can't tell now what it was) when I want to add specific style from style.xml as xml attribute set in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LevelListDrawable for this as following:

```
LevelListDrawable mLevels;
mLevels = (LevelListDrawable)getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.stat_levels);
```

**stat_levels** is xml file in drawables contains following thing;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/stat_0" />
<item android:maxLevel="10" android:drawable="@drawable/stat_10" />
<item android:maxLevel="20" android:drawable="@:drawable/stat_20" />
<item android:maxLevel="40" android:drawable="@drawable/stat_40" />
<item android:maxLevel="60" android:drawable="@drawable/stat_60" />
<item android:maxLevel="80" android:drawable="@drawable/stat_80" />
<item android:maxLevel="100" android:drawable="@:drawable/stat_100" />
</level-list>
```

stat_0 - stat_100 are drawables of different levels.

this can be used to set level on your need bases:`mLevels.setLevel(mLevel);`

mLevel can be maxLevel i.e 0, 10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100.